Horror movie with a masked serial killer; scenes in party and sauna
Actually, I'm not entirely sure if he's masked or not but he looks really creepy, like a guy doll that's smiling spastically all the time. Some scenes are remember are:

He was trying to chase some people and kill them at a party I think, and they hid under the benches of the sauna room.
He suddenly appeared at the door of a woman's apartment where she was sleeping and it was very windy.

I think it is a 90s or 00s movie, and it is probably an American film.
Does anyone know which movie this is?!

Omg it is VALENTINE!! thank you so much :)

@Trescool No problem, but please approve the question by clicking on the check mark.

Sounds very much like the slasher film Valentine from 2001 with Denise Richards, David Boreanaz and Katherine Heigl. From Rotten Tomatoes:

The novel by author Tom Savage becomes this horror film centered on a romantic holiday. Sixteen years ago, an unpopular college freshman named Victor DiMorta was the victim of a savagely cruel practical joke enacted by a quartet of beautiful female co-eds. The prank went horribly wrong, leading to Victor's expulsion and his subsequent murder of his abusive parents. Transformed by a decade in prison and some expensive plastic surgery into a handsome new man, Victor still harbors a grudge against the women who ruined his life. On each of the last three Valentine's Days, he has murdered one of them. Now, as the holiday approaches again, only one of the four remains alive, and she doesn't know which of her male acquaintances is the homicidal Victor.

The killer there wears a creepy doll mask and when he attacks people at a party, one girl runs and hides under a bench in a sauna. Here's the trailer:



